# Can't find XConnect instance after installing Sitecore XP1

Tags: xconnect, upgrade

I used the installation script for an XP1 scaled 9.1 instance, which includes a bunch of json files for xconnect:

[image]

however after successfully running .\XP1-SingleDeveloper.ps1 I cannot find an IIS instance for xconnect.

**Question**

Am I supposed to have one such instance? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not have such an instance. A single xConnect instance you will have on XP0.

on XP1 you have next application roles:

[image]

Here are described every role what is doing:

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/application-roles.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But the documentation about xDB Migration Tool explicitly says,

"On your xConnect instance, in the xconnect\App_Config\ConnectionStrings.configfile,replace the name of the old reporting database with the name of the new one". Where is the xConnect instance in my case?